# Palindrome checking code does not work inside def

Tags: python

Can anyone check why this palindrome checking function is not working?

```
def palindrome(a):
    b = (str(a)[::-1])
    if a == b:
        print("palindrome")
    else:
        print("not palindrome")

palindrome(121)
```

output

```
not palindrome
```

Comment: `a` (`121`) is not equal to `b` (`"121"`).

Comment: You are comparing an `int`with a `str`. If anything within your function, you can typecast the value to string: `a = str(a)`.

Comment: thanks dude it worked I've been stuck on this for hours cant notice one silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a is not a string so just add this code to it before the if statement.
`a = str(a)`